# Where can I find this article of Doléans-Dade?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

I need to find the article "Intégrales stochastiques dépendant d’un paramètre" by Doléans-Dade.
I could not find a pdf version online, and my university library does not have a printed version.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I would just ask for an interlibrary loan, that is what these services are for --- it's not online because of copyright restrictions.

Comment: A more complete citation: Doléans-Dade, C.: Intégrales stochastiques dépendant d'un paramètre. Publ. Inst. Statist. Univ. Paris16, 23–34 (1967)

Comment: Have you tried the following link? (I haven't.) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266985800_Integrales_stochastiques_dependant_d'un_parametre